# Why does the function modify original string in C?

Tags: c, string, for-loop, pointers

I have this function:

```
int main()
{
    char *org = "hello world";
    printf("original: %s\n", org);
    char *newString = removeCharacterInString(org, 2);
    printf("%s", newString);
    printf("\n%s", org);
    return 0;
}

static char *removeCharacterInString(char *str, int i) // removes character on n-th index 
{
    for (; i < strlen(str) - 1; i++)
    {
        str[i] = str[i+1];
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

And for some reason the function modifies the original string as well, I thought that in C the parameter is passed by value, so what can be the issue? Thank you

Comment: Yes, the _pointer_ to the string is passed by value, the string itself is now modified through the pointer.

Comment: How can it not modify it, if you are modifying the character array your pointer is pointing to?

Comment: The program also has _undefined behavior_ because it modifies a[n anonymous array object defined by a] string literal.

Comment: Also, since you are returning pointer to static char from function `removeCharacterInString` , so you should also define `newString` in main to have datatype of pointer to static char. Compiler may have flagged a warning for this

Comment: As Ian Abbott said, you must declare the array `org` as `char org[]="Hello World"` so that you are able to modify it if you want to. This is because the declaration `char *org="Hello World"` is equivalent to `const char org[]="Hello World"`

Comment: Basically C does not have a string class and that non-existing string class is not called `char`. You need to study arrays, then pointers, then strings, in that order.

Comment: @ShahFahad `removeCharacterInString` is returning a `char *`. The `static` keyword gives the function internal linkage and has nothing to do with the return type.

Comment: @ShahFahad `char *org="Hello World";` and `const char org[]="Hello World";` are not really equivalent although attempted modification of either string will result in _undefined behavior_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of *pointer to the string* is copied as the argument, but *the string pointed at by the pointer* is not copied. To copy strings, you should use some functions for that.

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc()
#include <string.h> // for strcpy()

static char *removeCharacterInString(char * str, int i) // removes character on n-th index 
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char* str2 = malloc(len + 1); // +1 for terminating null-character
    if (str2 == NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy(str2, str);

    for (; i < (int)len-1 ; i++)
    {
       str2[i] = str2[i+1];
    }
    str2[i] = '\0';
    return str2;
}
```

Comment: Or use `strdup` to do the calculation, allocation and copying in one go.

Comment: @iBug - `strdup` is not part of the standard library, so it may not be available for a particular implementation.  But yes, if you have it available and you're not planning to port the code, then you might as well use it and save some time.

Comment: @JohnBode They've proposed to sneak in `strdup` into the standard with the upcoming C2x. But for now you are correct :)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you are passing is not a string, but a pointer to a string. The parameter itself (the `str` pointer) can be altered within the function and the caller won't notice anything. You can give `str` a new value, and `newString` won't change at all.

BUT

The block of memory the pointer is pointing to, is a different story. You are manipulating such memory within your function. If this memory block is visible from more than one function, all of them will see the changes you make. In this case, `main()` and your `removeCharacterInString()` function.